# Как запустить проект VSCode в фоновом режиме через Jenkins?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, jenkins

Мне нужно запустить свой проект, после чего локально активируется сервер, с которым я уже буду работать дальше. Я пытаюсь автоматизировать это через Дженкинс.

Локально я запускаю команду

```
code --extensionDevelopmentPath=Path
```

После этого откроется VSCode и запустятся мои скрипты.

Выполнив ту же команду в Jenkins

```
script {
  stage('browser') {
    sh "pwd"
    dir('./path_main') {
        sh "pwd"
        sh "code --extensionDevelopmentPath=Path"
        sh "sleep 60"
    }
  }
}
```

Ничего не происходит. Можно ли запустить проект через Дженкинса?

Answer (score 2):

В VS Code нет консольного режима. Этому приложению обязательно нужно где-то нарисовать окошко.

В jenkins VS Code запускается от имени другого пользователя.  У него нет дисплея, поэтому приложение не сможет "открыться". Что у вас в логе jenkins?

Что делать.

Я нашел статью на сайте майкрософт про [CI для VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/continuous-integration)

Так вот, там на одном из шагов запускают Xvfb - виртуальный X server (framebuffer), который "рисует" в памяти, а не на экране:

```
/usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

При прогоне тестов выставляют переменную окружения `DISPLAY=:99.0`. Тем самым для VS Code эмулируется возможность графического вывода.

Я думаю, вам в проекте jenkins надо поступить так же.